# Sending a php array as a dialogflow response

Tags: php, dialogflow-es

Hey I am building a chatbot using dialogflow and I am generating the responses by using a customized Webhook (I am programming in php). I am extracting data from my database and storing it in an array but when I send the array as a response to dialogflow it only shows the first row.
Here is my code:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$time = date("H:i:s");
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$request = json_decode($json, true);
$input = fopen("log_json.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($input,$json);
fclose($input);

function processMessage($update) {
   if($update["queryResult"]["action"] == "ques"){
     $bdd= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=****', '****', '***', array(
     PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")) ;
     $data = array();
     $nom= $update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["nom_aliment"];
     $info=$update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["Information"];
     $quantite=$update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["Quantite"];
     $req=$bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM TableCiqual WHERE alim_nom LIKE ? ");
     $req->execute(array("%$nom%"));
     while($resultat=$req->fetch()){  
        $variab=$resultat[$info]*$quantite/100;
        $ppp =$resultat['alim_nom'].' '.$info.' : '.$variab;
         $data=$ppp;
     }
     sendMessage(array(
        "source" => $update["responseId"],
        "fulfillmentText"=>$data,
        "payload" => array(
            "items"=>[
                array(
                    "simpleResponse"=>
                array(
                    "textToSpeech"=>"Bad request"
                     )
                )
            ],
            ),
       
       ));
       }
     }
     function sendMessage($parameters) {
         echo json_encode($parameters);
     }
```

I know that my query returns multiple results all these results are stored in the array $data that I send as a response in dialogflow. The problem is that dialogflow only shows me the first row of the array $data instead of the whole array with all the rows.
My question is : Is it possible to send an array as a response in dialogflow and if yes how so.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two issues here.

The first is that `$data` is not actually containing a list of your results. The line

$data = $ppp;

is assigning `$ppp`, which is a string, to `$data` rather than adding on to the end of the array. I think, for that line, you want something more like

```
$data[] = $ppp;
```

However, this doesn't solve your problem completely, since the `fulfillmentText` attribute in JSON isn't expecting an array - it is expecting a string. So you probably want to concatenate all of those entries with something like

```
"filfillmentText" => implode( "\n", $data );
```

However, this assumes that you both want a new line in between each answer and that the chat system you're using supports the feature this way - not all do. (And you haven't indicated which one you're using.)

Comment: Thank you very much yes I discovered that Dialogflow only takes string as a result but the implode is not working correctly the results aren't showing in new lines instead i have all my results on the same line. Do you know how can I solve my problem?

Comment: Answer updated. Keep in mind that how a chat client displays it depends on that client.